# Sending .send requests in loop only sets the last value of the loop i amount of times

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

```
setCountries (e){

    Object.keys(countries).forEach((key) => {
        const country = countries[key];
        const attDef = Math.round(countryProps.POP_EST / 1000);
        const price = countryProps.POP_EST;

        this.contract.methods.createCountry(country.name, attDef, attDef, this.account).send(this.contractObject, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                console.log(res)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

When I log a country like the following:

```
getCountryPrice = (id) => {
    this.contract.methods.getCountryPrice(id).call(this.contractObject, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
}
```

I know it's not the smart contract that is the problem since i tested it thoroughly in Remix and with seperate country pushes. I use web3 and Metamask.

If this is the countries object :

```
    {
"AL":{"name":"AL","id":0,"worldId":4},
"AX":{"name":"AX","id":1,"worldId":5},
"AD":{"name":"AD","id":2,"worldId":6}
}
```

all values in solidity seemed to be set to AD

Comment: check batchrequests http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html?highlight=batch#batchrequest

Comment: I used batch request before and tried it again with batches, it still does not work though..